# Freeradius, authenticate via BASH script, authorize via LDAP group membership?

Tags: bash, ldap, freeradius

I have a custom ubuntu container containing Freeradius within a kubernetes cluster. Due to how containers work, the normal SAMBA/Winbind method of Freeradius/AD integration is not an option, so I wrote a BASH script to authenticate user credentials, and I also have the LDAP module installed to authorize users for particular services based on group membership.

At the moment I've only been able to configure Freeradius to authorize based on group membership, without it basing its decision on the result of the script. I have tried a many different configurations of the authorize file, but I will show just a couple here. This one grants access even with a bad password:

```
DEFAULT  Auth-Type = Accept
         Exec-Program = "/path/to/script/auth.sh %{User-Name} %{User-Password}",
         Fall-Through = Yes
DEFAULT  Ldap-Group == "Admingroup", Auth-Type := Accept
         Service-Type = Administrative-User,
         cisco-avpair ='shell:priv-lvl=15'
DEFAULT  Auth-Type := Reject
         Reply-Message = "Authorization failed."
```

And this one denies access irrespective of the credentials supplied:

```
DEFAULT  Ldap-Group == "Admingroup", Exec-Program = "/path/to/script/auth.sh %{User-Name} %{User-Password}", Auth-Type := Accept
         Service-Type = Administrative-User,
         cisco-avpair ='shell:priv-lvl=15'
DEFAULT  Auth-Type := Reject
         Reply-Message = "Authorization failed."
```

I know that my script works in and of itself since I have tested it independently of Freeradius, and I know that there is nothing wrong with the configuration of the LDAP module itself since it can connect to AD to test group membership. I primarily suspect that the configuration of the authorize file is the problem here, however feel free to ask about any of the other config files, I will say though that apart from radiusd.conf, clients.conf, and ldap, all other files will be in their default state from when they were installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. Here is the correct config for authorize:

```
DEFAULT  Ldap-Group == "Admingroup", Auth-Type := Accept
         Exec-Program-Wait = "/path/to/script/auth.sh %{User-Name} %{User-Password}",
         Service-Type = Administrative-User,
         cisco-avpair ='shell:priv-lvl=15'
DEFAULT  Auth-Type := Reject
         Reply-Message = "Authorization failed."
```

Also, the exec module had to be modified at /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/exec. The "wait" variable needs to be set to yes so that freeradius can use the exit code of the script to determine whether to accept or reject:

```
exec {
        wait = yes
        input_pairs = request
        shell_escape = yes
        timeout = 2
}
```